# HTML Select styled

Tags: html, css, select, styles, onchange

I have this button, that should go to the page in the value, but it don't when i have the css, without it works, but looks bad:

```
<form action="table.php" name="rows" method="POST">
    <select class="styledselect_pages" onchange="window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="table.php?row=100">100</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And this CSS:

```
.styledselect_pages {
    background              :url(../images/table/select_number_rows.gif) left no-repeat;
    border                  :none;
    border-left             :none;
    color                   :#393939;
    cursor                  :pointer;
    display                 :block;
    font-family             :Arial;
    font-size               :12px;
    height                  :20px;
    line-height             :16px;
    margin                  :0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding                 :4px 0 0 6px;
    text-align              :left;
    width                   :130px;
}
```

Why don't the "Onchange" not work?

Comment: Maybe i should have added some more "options", hope you get it :)

Comment: Try removing individual style rules until it starts working again, in order to identify which rule is breaking it. Bear in mind that `<select>` elements are basically unstylable due to being external form components, so if you want it to better fit your theme you may be better off creating your own subtitute for it.

Comment: Did remove the styles one by one, and it is cuz the class is in the select tag it breaks

Comment: There's likely something else on the page that's conflicting. Do you have an event listener on the class? Are you having PHP or another language output the above HTML to the page? Maybe you need to escape your quotes. The above code as it stands should work fine.

Comment: It does work as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNzXW/

Comment: I have a <div class="clear"></div> and no PHP yet but alot of JavaScripts

Comment: Well, go ahead and paste in the code which might be causing the conflict.

Comment: The `onchange` attribute does not work, since the option cannot be changed: there is just one option. If you add another option, it works. Your problem with styling is unspecified, and the functional problems you may have are not illustrated in your code snippet. The heading of the question is apparently misleading, as this does not seem to be about styling, really.

Comment: the onchange works in jsfiddle even with the css

Comment: Can my Javascripts have something to do with this,

Comment: If you keep using the plural form of Javascript, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work irrespective of the style, because the `select` has only one `option` which is selected by default. When you try selecting it again, there is no change of value in the `select` and so the `onchange` event is not fired.

Two ways to make this work:

1. Adding a dummy `option` to the `select` (`<option value=''>---</option>`)
2. Changing `onchange` to `onblur` event.

I would prefer the first option because it is more sensible out of the two. Also, consider calling a function rather than having inline Javascript code.

`<select onchange='javascript:getrow(this.value);'>`

```
<script>
function getrow(no) {
    if (no!='')
        location.href = 'table.php?row='+no;
}
</script>
```